# How to export GEDI data to drive from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to export and download the GEDI data to a tabular data format. I tried the following to save as a geotiff file, but nothing shows up in the google drive. Any alternative way to just extract the exact lat,lon and values would be useful to me.

```
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(image=dataset,
                                     description='gedi',
                                     scale=30,
                                     region=lyon,
                                     fileNamePrefix='gedi',
                                     crs='EPSG:4326',
                                     fileFormat='GeoTIFF'
                                     )
task.start()
```

Code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Aq195idPLeD8DAbjrYgMjHrBPW2hi320?usp=sharing

[image: GEDI plot using Earth Engine]

Answer (score 0):

You can export it with this code:

```
var qualityMask = function(im) {
  return im.updateMask(im.select('quality_flag').eq(1))
      .updateMask(im.select('degrade_flag').eq(0));
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI02_A_002_MONTHLY')
                  //.filterDate(start_date, end_date)
                  .map(qualityMask)
                  .select('rh98')
                  .filterBounds(geometry);

var GEDImean = dataset.mean()

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: GEDImean,
  folder: 'GEDI',
  description: 'GEDI_dataset_region',
  region: geometry
});
```