# How to export GEDI monthly raster data to drive from Google Colab

Tags: export, google-colab, gedi

I am trying to export and download the GEDI data to a tabular data format. I tried the following to save as a geotiff file, but nothing shows up in the google drive.

The link is

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_h0Kd9PqEjcMltiYL0m0YXWQvbi3U1qv#scrollTo=qWu_DIfoCGNs

Comment: The colab notebook is not accessible.

Comment: Have you checked this:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/439830/how-to-export-gedi-data-to-drive-from-google-earth-engine/460183#460183